# Cannot open modal when click the button

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-props

So, when i click the cart button, the modal should be open since i passed the openModal fuction down to the cart button, but when i click on the cart button, nothing happens, please help me to find out what wrong with my codes! Thank you so much!

context.js:

```
class ProductProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
    detailProduct: detailProduct,
    cart: [],
    modalOpen: false,
    modalProduct: detailProduct
  };

  getItem = (id) => {
    const product = this.state.products.find((item) => item.id === id);
    return product;
  };

  addToCart = (id) => {
    let tempProducts = [...this.state.products];
    const index = tempProducts.indexOf(this.getItem(id));
    const product = tempProducts[index];
    product.inCart = true;
    product.count = 1;
    const price = product.price;
    product.total = price;

    this.setState(() => {
      return (
        { products: tempProducts, cart: [...this.state.cart, product] },
        () => console.log(this.state)
      );
    });
  };

  openModal = (id) => {
    const product = this.getItem(id);
    this.setState(() => {
      return { modalProduct: product, openModal: true };
    });
  };

  closeModal = (id) => {
    this.setState(() => {
      return { modalOpen: false };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          addToCart: this.addToCart,
          openModal: this.openModal,
          closeModal: this.closeModal
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Product.js:

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title, img, price, inCart } = this.props.product;
    return (
      <ProductWrapper clasName="col-9 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-3">
        <div className="card">
          <ProductContext.Consumer>
            {(value) => (
              <div className="img-container p-5">
                <Link to={`/details/${id}`}>
                  <img src={img} alt="product" className="card-img-top" />
                </Link>

                <button
                  className="cart-btn"
                  onClick={() => {
                    value.addToCart(id);
                    value.openModal(id);
                  }}
                  disabled={inCart ? true : false}
                >
                  {inCart ? (
                    <p className="text-capitalize mb-0">In Cart</p>
                  ) : (
                    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                  )}
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </ProductContext.Consumer>
          <div className="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p className="align-self-center mb-0">{title}</p>
            <h5 className="text-blue mb-0">
              <span className="mr-1">$</span>
              {price}
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ProductWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Modal.js:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ProductConsumer>
        {(value) => {
          const { modalOpen, closeModal } = value;
          const { img, title, price } = value.modalProduct;
          if (!modalOpen) {
            return null;
          } else {
            return (
              <ModalContainer>
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div
                      className="col-8 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-5 text-center text-capitalize"
                      id="modal"
                    >
                      <h5>item added to cart</h5>
                      <img src={img} className="img-fluid" alt="" />
                      <h5>{title}</h5>
                      <h5 className="text-muted">price : ${price}</h5>
                      <Link to="/">
                        <ButtonContainer
                          onClick={() => {
                            closeModal();
                          }}
                        >
                          Continue Shopping
                        </ButtonContainer>
                      </Link>
                      <Link to="/cart">
                        <ButtonContainer
                          cart
                          onClick={() => {
                            closeModal();
                          }}
                        >
                          Go To Cart
                        </ButtonContainer>
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ModalContainer>
            );
          }
        }}
      </ProductConsumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Sanbox link for better observation: https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-buz0u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your sandbox is likely not working as expected to show the problem. Please fix and I am happy to have a look.

Comment: i fixed it:https://codesandbox.io/s/why-cant-i-fetch-data-from-a-passed-value-forked-buz0u?file=/src/App.js. Please check! Thank you!

Comment: Oh, please redirect the url above my rendering to productlist like this "https://buz0u.csb.app/productlist" otherwise you wouldn't see all my products being rendered